# Maximal Modulus Principle Theorem for a Compact Set

Tags: complex-analysis

The theorem says: The maximum of the absolute value of an analytic function over some compact set in a domain of analyticity is attained at the boundary of that compact set.

Could someone please explain why it is true?

Comment: Your textbook doesn't include a proof? (There are several reasonable ways to prove this, depending on which order the author prefers to do things.)

Comment: @mrf No, I have it in my notes with no proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively it is true because an interior point $z_0$ *cannot* have a local maximum of the modulus. If the function is not constant, then developing it as a power series around $z_0$ will yield:
$$ f(z) = a_0 + a_n(z-z_0)^n + o((z-z_0)^n) $$
for some $n\ge 1$ and some $a_n\ne 0$, in some neighborhood of $z_0$. Thus, no matter what $a_n$ and $n$ are, we can find *some* point in the neighborhood of $z_0$ where the modulus is larger than $|a_0|$. Therefore there is no maximum of the modulus at $z_0$ when $z_0$ is an interior point.

On the other hand $|f(z)|$ is a continuous function of $z$ and must attain its maximum *somewhere* on a compact set. Since that somewhere cannot be an interior point, it can only be on the boundary.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me what you meant by $o((z-z_0)^{n})$?

Comment: @MATH: $o((z-z_0)^n)$ the [Landau symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) for a term that goes to $0$ strictly faster than $(z-z_0)^n$ does, when $z\to z_0$.

Answer (score 2):

While @HenningMakholm's answer is terrific, I thought I'd add a different perspective which I like quite a lot. The Cauchy integral property is a fundamental result in complex analysis which states that if a function $f$ is analytic in some region $\Omega$ with $z_0\in \Omega$ and simple closed loop $\gamma\subset\Omega$ which encircles $z_0$, $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz.$$ We can apply this to the maximum modulus principle. Suppose $f$ is analytic on a compact set $C\subset\mathbb C$ and reaches a maximum modulus at some point $z_0$ in the interior of $C$. Then there exists $R>0$ such that the disk of radius $R$ centered at $z_0$ is contained in $C$. Then for all $r\leq R$, $$|f(z_0)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}r dz\leq \frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_{|z-z_0|=r}|f(z_0)|dz=|f(z_0)|.$$ Since we have the first term and the last term in the above inequality are the same, the entire string of inequalities are actually equal, so $|f(z_0)|$ must be equal to the average value of $|f(z)|$ on the circle $|z-z_0|=r$. Since $|f(z_0)|$ is the maximum modulus of the function, the only way for this to be true is if $|f(z)|=|f(z_0)|$ for all $|z-z_0|=r$, and for each $r<R$. Now we have shown that the modulus is constant in a disk. We can apply the same technique to each point in the disk, and so on until we have shown that the function is constant over the entire compact set $C$.

Note that this method requires a subtlety left out of the theorem statement which is that the interior of $C$ be connected.